# Function called with another function as parameter, can't quite grasp concept of it

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I have a simple function declaration:

```
repeat = (n, action) => {
     for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
          action(i);
     }
}
```

Later in the page I call the repeat function, but use another function as the 'action' parameter:

```
let test_array = [];
     repeat(5, p => {
          test_array.push(p);
     })
```

This code should store 1,2,3,4,5 into the 'test_array' array, but I can't quite figure what exactly 'p' does in this situation.

Comment: You are passing a function to `repeat`. That function expects to be passed an argument (`p`). `repeat` calls the function passing an argument `action(i)`. It's no different from any other function. Here is a simple example: `function echo (x) { console.log(x); }; echo("foo bar");`. Here `echo` expects to be passed a single argument, assign ed to `x`. Then I call `echo` passing a string value.

Comment: How is 'p' able to detect the values when repeat is called?

Comment: `repeat` contains a loop. Each iteration of the loop calls a function passing `i` as argument. The current value of `i` will be assigned to `p`. Again, there is nothing special about this. It's how functions work. I think you are getting confused by the fact that you are passing a function to another function. However, you seem to understand just fine that when calling `repeat(5, ...)`, `5` is assigned to `n` and the function is assigned to `action`. The same thing happens when you call `action(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, p is more or less a callback function. A callback is a function that is to be executed after another function has finished executing.

In your case you are creating another function which is where your p is being used.

You can see this by just logging your p var. p is a function (callback) in your code so you should see a function be outputted.

```js
repeat = (n, action) => {
     console.log("Action: ", action);
     for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
          action(i);
     }
}


let test_array = [];
repeat(5, p => {
    test_array.push(p);
})
```

Your code is the same as having:

```js
repeat = (n, action) => {
     for(i=1; i<=n; ++i) {
     console.log(action);
          action(i);
     }
}


let test_array = [];
repeat(5, function(i) {
    test_array.push(i);
})
     
     
console.log(test_array);
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function

Answer (score 0):

`p` is being used as the **parameter** to the anonymous function you are providing to `repeat()`. (Check out the [MDN overview of functions in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions))

You could just as easily assign a non-anonymous (i.e. named) function to the call to `repeat`, as **functions are first-class in JavaScript**

```
function foo(i) {
  test_array.push(i);
}

repeat(5, foo); // => test_array now holds [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] just like before
```